# what to select and copy from web view in file?

Tags: android-webview

i had an to devlop an app in Android in which i had to select some text and copy text from webview in to my local file.how do to implement it.
give a solution to work it out.

Thanks Ayrina

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    objWebview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView_engine);
    //enable javaScript overall
    WebSettings objWebsetting =objWebview.getSettings();
    objWebsetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

 // Enable JavaScript Alerts
    objWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
  //  Button btnSelect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCopy);

    objWebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    selectAndCopyText(objWebview);
}
void selectAndCopyText(WebView view)
{
    try
    {
        KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                                                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0);
        shiftPressEvent.dispatch(view);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("dd", "Exception in emulateShiftHeld()", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: void selectAndCopyText(WebView view)
{
    try
    {
        KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                                                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0);
        shiftPressEvent.dispatch(view);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("dd", "Exception in emulateShiftHeld()", e);
    }
}


Implemented this method but unable copy the webview text onTouch Method